# App Icon not appearing on device with TestFlight installed app iOS 15

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, appicon

I have noticed on iOS 15, when I install an app from TestFlight, my app icon is not appearing on the device.  Only placeholder for app icon appears on physical device.

All app icon assets for every resolution are correctly added to Assets.  The app icon appears in the test flight app and in appstoreconnect everywhere including TestFlight and builds.

The only place it doesn't appear is on the device.  It appears normally on the simulator.

The only fix I found was to add a version of the app to add a build where you submit for review and save it.  No need to submit.  Then install from TestFlight and reboot device.  The problem is as soon as I uploaded a new build to TestFlight it stopped showing icon and had to go through this silly process again.

I have never had this issue with past apps and wondering what the issue is and how to resolve it.

Comment: Create a new AppIcon asset. There are new sizes.

Comment: It's a new Xcode project with version 13.1 and correct asset sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue with testflight on iOS 15. I found this from apple developer forum that might of help:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682648

According to the accepted answer by @vladweinstein, a temporary solution is to restart the device after installing the app.

This works for me too.

Answer (score 0):

We are still having the same issue with TestFlight apps (iOS 14.7 and iOS 15+)
The only solution we found is to restart the device as Raphael Rex mentioned.